# ng2-toastr not working in angular 4 application

Tags: angular, toastr

ng2-toastr message is working fine when it is inside:

```
data => {
        this.toastr.info('OOPS!!!', 'Information!');
        this.dictData = data;
        console.log(this.dictData);
        this.results = data.results;
        console.log(this.results);

      } ,
```

But not working when it is inside:

```
   error => {
            console.log("some error occured");
            console.log(error.errorMessage);
            this.toastr.error('OOPS!!!', 'Error!');
            if (error.status === 404) {
              this.router.navigate(['/errornotfound']);
            }
}
```

Not able to understand why it is behaving this way.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: try this.toastr.info inside error section and see whether it's working . Just to make sure it's not related to error method in toastr

Comment: yes i have tried it but not working

Comment: Will you be able to post entire code block?

Comment: here is the github link with entire code:

Comment: https://github.com/saisreereddy/Project1

Comment: Looking at it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happening. When there is an error you immediately redirect to **error page** from the **fullpageview**. But your toast configured in **FullpageviewComponent**. So it's actually showing the error message. But you already navigated to error page and because of that you can't see the toast.

You can check that theory by commenting out the error redirection like below:

```
error => {
        console.log("some error occured");
        console.log(error.errorMessage);
        this.toastr.info('OOPS!!!', 'Information!');
        // if (error.status === 400) {
        //   this.router.navigate(['/errorbadrequest']);
        // }
        // if (error.status === 404) {
        //   this.router.navigate(['/errornotfound']);
        // }
        // if (error.status === 403) {
        //   this.router.navigate(['/errorauthenticationfailed']);
        // }
        // if (error.status === 414) {
        //   this.router.navigate(['/errorurltoolong']);
        // }
      }
```

**Solution 01:**

You can show the toast in the **error page** instead of **FullpageviewComponent**

**Solution 02:**

Show error toast in the **FullpageviewComponent** and then navigate to error page. For this you need to use **onToastClose** kind of event.

**Solution 03:**

Another solution is to create separate service to show toast messages. Configure the toast in root level of your app. In this way you don't have to add the toast in every components.

Hope this helps :)